# MEAN Angular 4 stack download csv file from server to client

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

This is my `NodeJs POST` function which I am calling from Angular 4 project.

```
var generateReport = function(req, res){
    const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
    connection((db) => {
          const fields = ['Gender', 'Name', 'Email'];
          myReport = [];
          db.collection('members_'+req.user._id).find()
          .toArray()
          .then(function(members){
            members.forEach(member => {
                db.collection('plans_'+req.user._id).findOne()
                .then(function(plan){
                    this.myReport.push({
                        "Gender" : member.gender,
                        "Name" : member.name,
                        "Email" : member.email
                    })
                    const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });
                    const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myReport);
                    var fs = require('fs');
                    res.status(200).send(new Buffer(csv));
                    /*fs.writeFile('csv.csv', csv, function (err) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      res.download('csv.csv');
                    });*/
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
            })
          }) 
    });
}
```

And I am getting error as :

```
 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
 at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
 at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
 at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expr                                                                               ess/lib/response.js:767:10)
 at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expres                                                                             s/lib/response.js:194:10)
 at /home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/controllers/data-controller.js:1959:22
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the cli                                                                             ent
 at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
 at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
 at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expr                                                                             ess/lib/response.js:767:10)
 at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expres                                                                             s/lib/response.js:194:10)
 at /home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/controllers/data-controller.js:1959:22
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the cli                                                                             ent
 at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
 at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
 at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expr                                                                             ess/lib/response.js:767:10)
 at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/node_modules/expres                                                                             s/lib/response.js:194:10)
 at /home/ubuntu/alpeshvasani/server/controllers/data-controller.js:1959:22 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I had tried other ways to send **csv** but it failed on angular side.. It send `httperror` as unable to parse **json**, as it is taking response in json form by default. so I changed it to `{ responseType: 'text' }` But No Luck.

Comment: Use next in function parameters and after   res.status(200).send(new Buffer(csv)); put return next()

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: The error “Error: Can’t set headers after they are sent.” means that you’re already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent

Comment: POSTMAN work great but same with angular 4 give me Above error

Comment: Can you point problem in my code ? @MohammadRaheem

Comment: I think problem in your for each loop , try to send res everytime not possible , you have to send one time res.send(), just for testing purpose you can check for one value without using loop

Comment: Use full. @MohammadRaheem